# How to authenticate an Asp.Net MVC 5 application against Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following context:

1. A Asp.NET MVC 5 web app that is client.
2. A Web API which communicates with Custom Db (Where Users table is located).

In the AccountController.cs , there is the method Login which uses SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsyn call .

I know I need to use an HttpClient to call the Web API "/Token" url to get the bearer token to be used, when getting API resources, and that this token can be stored in a cookie.

What I need here is make the client web app know that user is logged in. 
Where should I place this logic (httpClient calling web api to validate user)  to make my client web app behaves like the user is authenticated (display email in top menu, access to [Authorize] controller methods, redirect to login page, all this in client web app). ?

Comment: Are the Web and WebAPI parts of your app within the same web project, or hosted separately?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309792/asp-net-identity-in-microservice-architecture/26310977#26310977