# Login via social (facebook, google etc.) on MVC and native mobile (Web API) on the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I'm developing an MVC web application (Asp.net C# - using AngularJS in the front).
Currently, the users can log in to the site using username & password or oauth providers (such as google and Facebook).

We have developed a native mobile application that uses our asp.net web-api.

We want the users will be able to login using the same credentials to the mobile app and the website.

In order to do so, both projects (web-api & web application) are using the same DB with ASP.Net Identity. For example, if the user has created an account using username & password, he can log in on both platforms.

The problem is with external providers (Facebook, google...), when a user create an account on the web view the identity saves the users on the DB with a specific provider key (on the AspNetUserLogins table).
And when the user login (or register) using the mobile app I only have the user token, and I don't know how to log the user in.

Then I've found this post:
[WebApi ASP.NET Identity Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092723/webapi-asp-net-identity-facebook-login)

which explains exactly what I've needed, only now I have 2 problems:

1. Using the user token (from the mobile login) I retrieve his user ID and save it on the AspNetUserLogins table, but when using the web application it saves a different user id, actually it calls that a Provider Key.
2. (Minor problem) For some reason, using the above link code, I don't get the user email but only his Facebook token and Facebook user id.

Please note,
* I want to use the native approach and can't use a web view on the mobile app because I want the app to use the user Facebook/google native application.
* Also read this: [ASP.NET Identity in Microservice Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309792/asp-net-identity-in-microservice-architecture/26310977#26310977) it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!
Shaul

Comment: Note that if the user changes its setting to not share the email, even if you ask for it in the Scopes, you will not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out the answers:

1. Turns out that the provider key is actually the app specific user id, i.e the user has a specific user id for each Facebook app.
2. In order to get the Email you should add a specific request for it in the scope in the startup.auth.cs:

   ```
   var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
   {
       AppId = DEFINITIONS.FACEBOOK_ID,
       AppSecret = DEFINITIONS.FACEBOOK_SECRET,

       Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
       {
           // This is for saving the data as user claims
           OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
           {
               context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, null, "Facebook"));
               context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:email", context.Email, null, "Facebook"));
               return Task.FromResult(0);
           }
       }

   };
   // This will help you get the Email
   facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email"); 
       app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
   ```